# Document with 3 subdocuments - each subdoc with own TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, titles, page-numbering, structure

I need to create a rather complicated document structure.

A main document contains 3 sub documents (think like the bible, new and old).

I need to start with a Main title page, a main TOC (containing all sections of all 3 subdocs) and a small introduction.

Then the subdocuments start with a titlepage, TOC and the contents of each own subdoc.

Preferably the page numbering should be like X-Y, where X is the subdoc and Y is the page of the subdoc.

An example structure:

```
Main tite page
Main TOC (all X-Y) ...........0-1
Introduction .................0-2
Title page Subdoc 1 
TOC Subdoc1 (only 1-Y)........1-1
Content Subdoc1 ..............1-2
Content Subdoc1 ..............1-3
Content Subdoc1 ..............1-4
Title page Subdoc 2 
TOC Subdoc2 (only 2-Y)........2-1
Content Subdoc2 ..............2-2
Content Subdoc2 ..............2-3
Content Subdoc2 ..............2-4
Title page Subdoc 3 
TOC Subdoc3 (only 3-Y)........3-1
Content Subdoc3 ..............3-2
Content Subdoc3 ..............3-3
Content Subdoc3 ..............3-4
```

I normally use the scrartcl class.
Hopefully you can point me in the right direction.

Thanks